# Number of integers whose gcd with 300 is 1

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Find the number of integers between 1 and 300 (including the ends)
whose gcd with 300 is 1.

What happens when when $'1'$ is changed to $'2'$?

My try:

Write $300$ as $2*2*3*5*5$

The required answer will be all the prime numbers between 5 and 300(is it correct?)

For second part I have no idea how to proceed

Will it be those numbers which have just 2 or multiples of 2 as factors(not 3 and 5)?

We can calculate numbers which are divisible by 3 and 5 till 300 and subtract it from 300.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Any $n=2u$ where $u$ is odd and not divisible by 3 or 5 will be counted "when 1 is changed to 2". That includes more than primes.

Comment: Is my first part when gcd is 1 correct?

Comment: For second part, there are 300 numbers. We can calculate numbers which are divisible by 3 and 5 and subtract it from 300. Will it give me the required answer?

Comment: Neither of your trys is right so far. But keep trying... it might be fun for you to see the approach and I don't want to spoil it...

Comment: I get it. For first part I  missed squares of 7,11,13 and 17 and those numbers which are formed by multiplying two prime numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you ask for is called the *totient* of $300$, written $\varphi(300)$. It can be shown that if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \dotsm p_k^{\alpha_k}$ where $p_i$ are primes and $\alpha_i > 0$, then:

$$\varphi(n) = n \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_1} \right)
                 \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_2} \right)
                 \dotsm
                 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p_k} \right)$$

In your case, $300 = 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, so

$$\varphi(300) = 300 \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right)
                     \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{3} \right)
                     \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{5} \right)
               = 80$$

Comment: What about when gcd is 2?